# Breaking a record triggered flow into single batches

Tags: apex, trigger, visual-workflow

We have an API that batch updates 200 Account records in parallel using the bulk API.

We are running into an issue where we need a specific Account record triggered flow to process the records in individual batches level rather than 200.

I tried using a scheduled path, but the issue with this approach is that I cannot use ISCHANGED logic inside of the flow.

Below is the logic I need, but I need to add **X6sense_Account_Buying_Stage__c** ISCHANGED

[image]

Is there a way to break up a bulk api update into single batches for processing for a specific flow?

I believe adding a wait element to the flow would solve this, but unfortunately, I cannot add this element inside of a synchronous flow.

What are my options?

Comment: the last radio button is effectively an ischanged on the field in question

Comment: @cropredy That last button is ISCHANGED for the condition, not for the individual fields. As you can see I have two values for the same field 6sense fields. I need this to run if the field changes, not if the condition changes.

Comment: check out this [help article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_forcecom_flow_fbuilder_trigger_specific_change.htm&type=5&release=228)